# Как отобразить текст привязанный к нижнему блоку поверх верхних

Tags: css

Имеется слайдер поверх, которого имеется слой с position:absolute. Необходимо, чтобы при прокрутке слайда его текст оказывался поверх последнего слоя. Использование z-index, даёт эффект только до начала перелистывания слайдов, а затем текст переходит под абсолютный блок(к слову он имеет прозрачность с помощью rgba()). Я так понимаю нужен скрипт, но вдруг проблему можно решить без него.

```
 //slider///
    <div id="viewport">
            <ul id="slidewrapper">
                <li class="slide">
                    <div class="slider-head-text">
                        <h1>lorem</h1>
                        <h2>lorem</h2>
                        <p>lorem</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/slider-img1.png" alt="1" class="slide-img"></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="img/15.jpg" alt="2" class="slide-img"></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="img/barocco1.jpg" alt="3" class="slide-img"></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="img/gostinaya1.jpg" alt="4" class="slide-img"></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="prev-next-btns">
                <div id="prev-btn"><img src="img/left-arrow-angle_icon-icons.com_74249.png" alt=""></div>
                <div id="next-btn"><img src="img/right-arrow-angle_icon-icons.com_74249.png" alt=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    ///css///
     #viewport {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
text-align: center;
  }

  #slidewrapper {
position: relative;
width: calc(100% * 4);
-webkit-transition: 1s;
-o-transition: 1s;
transition: 1s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.67,.01,.23,1);
-o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.67,.01,.23,1);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.67,.01,.23,1);
  }


  ////overlay
   <div class="slider-nav-wrap">
            <ul id="nav-btns">
                <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
                <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
                <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
                <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="button-block">
                <button>Подробнее</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        ///css
     .slider-nav-wrap {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 90vh;
top: 135px;
left: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
     }

     //// TEXT css
    .slider-head-text {
position: absolute;
width: 500px;
color:#fff;
z-index: 999;
top: 140px;
left: 20%;
text-align: left;
  }
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код - без него ничего не понятно

Comment: Вот в принципе так...

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

задай position: relative для .slide а не для #slidewrapper 
также для .slider-head-text {width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left:0;}, z-index не нужен а сами h1, h2, p  оберни в какой-то див и его можешь позиционировать с помощью margin и padding, задай ему ширину, если нужно